# find remote hostname with ssh command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to find remote hostname and disk volume of remote server through ssh command.

```
ssh user@remotehost echo $(df -B1G $vol|awk 'NR==2{printf "%s %dGB/%dGB\n",$5,$3,$2}') $(hostname) $vol
```

the output of disk comes as expected, but hostname and vol in command gives output that of localhost and volume. The output I get is:

```
diskusgae% usedGB/totalGB localhost volume_on_localhost
```

Can anyone guide on how can I get desired output?

```
diskusgae% usedGB/totalGB remotehost volume_on_remotehost
```

Comment: Quote your commands like `"command1 && commands2"` or perhaps `"command1; command2"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this syntax to avoid '\" mess

```
ssh -q $host bash <<- \EOF
    vol=/dev/mapper/vg1-home
    df -B1G $vol | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s %dGB/%dGB",$5,$3,$2}'
    printf " $HOSTNAME $vol"
EOF
```

Or like this in case of sh

```
ssh -q $host sh <<- \EOF
    vol=/dev/mapper/vg1-home
    df -B1G $vol | awk 'NR==2{printf "%s %dGB/%dGB",$5,$3,$2}'
    printf " %s $vol" $(hostname)
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I actually need the output in one line.